# Am i going wrong?? using view ondraw and thread to make a animate game

Tags: android

i am new to android apps ,
i just start to write a simple game.
I used a Class extends View and using some thread to make a simple game
i wanna ask if i go wrong direction ? should i use other way to do it?
I think i am wrong on using thread in here right??
I just use

```
Game gameview;
gameview= new Game(this);
setContentView(gameview);
```

to call this in class which extends activity

```
public class Game extends View {
Bitmap background;
Bitmap nomouthbear;
Bitmap nomouthbearget;
Bitmap apple;
float bearX;
float bearY;
List<Apple> appleList;
int appleCount = 0;
float appleX;
float appleY;
float applescore;
float applespeed;
int totalscore = 0;
float canvasheight;
float canvaswidth;
float randomNumber;// random number for apple appear in X
float randomNumber2;// random number for score and speed
float randomNumber3;
int applecombo = 0; // count for how many apple that the bear eat in combo
boolean checkbeareat; // for check if bear eat any of apple or not.
boolean bearEating = false;
Thread thread2;
boolean ineatingthread = false;

int time = 20; // game time =60sec

public Game(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // setup image source
    nomouthbear = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.nomouthbear_net);
    apple = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apple);
    nomouthbearget = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.nomouthbearget);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.background);
    // init bear x,y
    bearX=0;
    bearY =0;
    // setup background
    if (background != null) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(background));
    }
    // open a list which hold all apple
    appleList = new ArrayList<Apple>();

    // make a thread to creat apple every 2 sec
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    sleep(2000);
                    randomNumber = (float) Math.random();
                    randomNumber2 = (float) Math.random();

                    // avoid start at edge point

                    appleX = canvaswidth * randomNumber;
                    if (appleX >= canvaswidth - apple.getWidth() / 2)
                        appleX = canvaswidth - apple.getWidth() / 2;
                    if (appleX <= nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2)
                        appleX = nomouthbear.getWidth();
                    applescore = 1000 * randomNumber2;
                    // check if speed too low
                    applespeed = 10 * randomNumber2;
                    if (applespeed <= 3) {
                        applespeed = 3;
                    }
                    // add new apple in the apple list
                    appleList.add(new Apple(appleX, 65, applescore,
                            applespeed));
                    appleCount++;

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    // start the thread
    thread.start();
    // thread for timer

    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true)

                {

                        sleep(1000);
                        if(time>=0)
                    time--;

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread1.start();

//thread for controlling the bear eat pic appear time       
    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true)

                {

                    if (bearEating == true) {

                            sleep(200);
                            bearEating = false;

                    }


                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread2.start();




}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);



    if (time <= 0) {
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        textPaint.setTextSize(65);
        canvas.drawText(
                "Game Over!",
                canvas.getWidth() / 4, canvas.getHeight() / 2, textPaint);
        canvas.drawText(
                "Your Score is ",
                canvas.getWidth() / 4, canvas.getHeight() / 2+65, textPaint);
        canvas.drawText(
                Integer.toString(totalscore),
                canvas.getWidth() / 4, canvas.getHeight() / 2+130, textPaint);






    } else {
        checkbeareat = false;
        canvasheight = canvas.getHeight();
        canvaswidth = canvas.getWidth();
        // draw score text
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        textPaint.setTextSize(65);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + Integer.toString(totalscore), 50, 50,
                textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("Time left: " + Integer.toString(time), 50, 120,
                textPaint);
        // if have apple
        if (appleCount != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < appleCount; i++) {
                if (appleList.get(i).checkstate()) {

                    // make every apple fall down

                    if ((appleList.get(i).getAppleY() + apple.getHeight() / 2) <= canvas
                            .getHeight()) {

                        appleList.get(i).setAppleY(
                                appleList.get(i).getAppleY()
                                        + appleList.get(i).getspeed());
                    } else {
                        // appleList.get(i).setAppleY(appleList.get(i).getAppleY());
                        applecombo = 0;
                        appleList.get(i).destoryApple();
                    }

                    // check if bear eat the apple

                    if (bearX + nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2 >= appleList
                            .get(i).getAppleX()
                            && bearX <= appleList.get(i).getAppleX()
                            && bearY>= appleList
                                    .get(i).getAppleY()
                            && bearY-nomouthbear.getHeight()/2 <= appleList.get(i).getAppleY()) {
                        // add score
                        totalscore += appleList.get(i).getAppleScore();
                        // change the state of apple to false so wont draw
                        // it
                        // again
                        appleList.get(i).destoryApple();
                        // draw bear ate
                        canvas.drawBitmap(nomouthbearget, bearX
                                - nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2, bearY
                                - nomouthbear.getHeight(), null);
                        checkbeareat = true;
                        bearEating = true;

                        applecombo++;

                    }

                    // draw apple
                    if (appleList.get(i).checkstate()) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(
                                apple,
                                appleList.get(i).getAppleX()
                                        - (apple.getWidth() / 2),
                                appleList.get(i).getAppleY()
                                        - (apple.getHeight() / 2), null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // draw bear
        // canvas.drawBitmap(nomouthbear, 0, 0, null);
        if (bearEating == false) {

                if (bearX == 0 && bearY == 0){

                    canvas.drawBitmap(nomouthbear, 0, canvas.getHeight()- nomouthbear.getHeight()*2, null);}

                else{
                    canvas.drawBitmap(nomouthbear,
                            bearX - nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2, bearY
                                    - nomouthbear.getHeight(), null);}


        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(nomouthbearget,
                    bearX - nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2,
                    bearY - nomouthbear.getHeight(), null);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (event.getX() >= nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2
            && event.getX() <= canvaswidth - nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2) {
        bearX = event.getX();
    } else if (event.getX() >= canvaswidth - nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2)
        bearX = canvaswidth - nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2;
    else
        bearX = nomouthbear.getWidth() / 2;

    bearY = canvasheight - nomouthbear.getHeight();

    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `invalidate` from `onDraw` -- `invalidate` is what causes `onDraw` to be called. If you want the view to update itself periodically then you should call `invalidate` at some interval from your thread (e.g. Thread1) by posting a runnable to the view.

In terms of multithreading your code is completely unsafe (i.e. it is unpredictable) -- there is no synchronization or even use of volatiles.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is only okay for the simplest of games, because it handles both rendering and computation in the UI thread, making it laggy when things get a bit more complicated.

You should be using a [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), check out its documentation and read up on [OpenGL in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

If you *really* do not want to use OpenGL, consider the regular [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), but be aware that it is a bit of a hassle to set up and it can't perform as smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simply game using View and onDraw but it is very slowly and very unprofesional. You cant create good game using it. To create game you should use openGL (GLSurfaceView).
I recomend you book: J. F. DiMarzio *Practical Android 4 Games Development* It's good book to learn using OpenGL on Android.